# Need Help Creating an Excel Formula To Compare UPCs

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Ok so I have tried to create a formula to compare a list of UPCs that get scanned into another sheet I have on the same document and this is as far as I got.

```
=MATCH(A1,Table2[[#All],[UPC]],0).
```

All this formula was able to do is give me an error if it doesn't exist and if it did find it it would output the row number. The ultimate end goal is to have to it compare the UPCs scanned into a pre-existing list and if it exist to have it output the row of information next to it in a new cell.

Also can I have this formula return text if it doesn't find the UPC? The final thing is if there is no UPC that is scanned in but the formula is still in place can I make it so it just doesn't output anything not even an error?

Comment: If anyone can answer, but needs more information please let me know.

Comment: All of that is possible with a combination of IF(), COUNTIF(), and MATCH(). You already have the MATCH() part handled. The basic flow will be: "Count now many times this value exists in the master list. Is it zero? Ok, then do nothing (return nothing by double quotes with nothing inside: ""). If it's not zero, then do the MATCH()."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing some research and finally found the perfect equation that seems to satisfy all of the criteria that I need. If any one else was wondering here is the final equation I came up with, =IF(ISBLANK(A1),"",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Table1[#All],3,FALSE),"CHECK UPC"))

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vlookup, sort the data in Table on the UPC column (if text) A to Z or smallest to largest if number and it should be first column in  `Table2`, other next column will be as index number 2,3,4,...A1:D2 correspond at the range in Table2. 
write this formula and choose instead of 2 the number of column you want the information from it, and False to get exact match
   `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A8,Table2!$A$1:$D$2,2,FALSE),"")`

Comment: Ok so this is looking like my best option so far but is there any way with a different equation that I could not have to sort the data in the UPC column from least to greatest as I would like to keep the data in the table nice and ordered. If not I'll most likely use this.

Comment: @Jack Setting the 4th argument to false makes vlookup do an exact search, which doesn't require a sorted table. The given formula should already work without sorting the table.

Comment: Sure like user2313067 said you can use the formula without sorting

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1). One thing to note though is that your list of UPCs will need to be sorted as VLOOKUP will stop as soon as it finds a value greater than the value you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

> =IF(COUNTIF(LookupRange,ThisUPC)=0,"",MATCH(ThisUPC,LookupRange,0))

As with Vlookup, MATCH does not require your data to be sorted so long as you set the third argument to zero (FALSE).

[image]